# Redirect posix file calls in C

Tags: c, posix, standard-library, io-redirection, posix-api

We have a "library" (a selection of code we would rather not change) that is written from the perspective that it has access to 2 files directly. It uses "open", "read" and "seek" posix calls directly on a file descriptor.

However, now we have a proprietary file system that cannot be accessed through standard IO calls. Seeing that we do not want to re-write the code, it would be great if we could redirect the IO calls to known functions that could then be used as an interface.

Is there any way of changing the calls used above so that the "read" and "seek" can be over-written with new function calls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say you don't want to change the library code, do you mean you want to use existing binary code, or just source? If you have the source and can recompile, I would simply pass `-Dread=my_read -Dopen=my_open` etc. to the compiler when building the library, and then provide your own `my_read` etc. functions.

Comment: Yes we can re-compile. This is a nice simple solution (hitting my head on why I did not think of that :) We are going to try out FUSE below, then revert back to this as FUSE seems to have a little more abstraction that we can use on other products where we cannot re-compile.

Comment: Even if you can't recompile, `objcopy` has a way to rename symbols in library files..

Comment: objcopy is quite cool. Used that often to hi-jack functions so we know when "hidden" APIs are being called :)

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can try is [**library function interposition**](http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23).

Comment: Nice. Did not know about this. Unfortunately the start-up is not something we can play with, but will definitely keep this in mind for debugging efforts.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to already mentioned function interposition and renaming function calls using a macro, another Linux-only option is to use [Filesystem in Userspace](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/). This way you can make your proprietary filesystem accessible to other applications which use the standard POSIX filesystem API. [FUSE hello world example](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/helloworld.html) is surprisingly short.

Comment: Awesome. We are going to give that a try and see if we can get that to work acceptably. We need quite high data throughput rate, so hopefully it can sustain the data rate. Otherwise it is a good suggestion. Thanks.